# How to Add Title to Legend?

Tags: matlab

I want to add a title to legend, as shown in the picture inside the red circle. How do I do that, knowing that I am using **Matlab 2014b** ?

This is the code I want to execute....

```
% Clear workspace.
clear all
% Clear command window.
clc
% Close all windows.
close all

% Compute Min Separation (dpt) two sources when pt1=2 and dx=0.5 and z=30
N = 3:1:20;
dpt1 = [7.75, 5.4, 4.13, 3.35, 2.82, 2.43, 2.14, 1.91, 1.72, 1.57, 1.44, 1.333, 1.24, 1.16, 1.088, 1.025, 0.97, 0.918];

% Compute Min Separation (dpt) two sources when pt1=2 and dx=0.5 and z=50
dpt2 = [12.88, 8.97, 6.884, 5.581, 4.695, 4.05, 3.56, 3.18, 2.87, 2.615, 2.405, 2.222, 2.068, 1.932, 1.815, 1.709, 1.615, 1.532];

% Compute Min Separation (dpt) two sources when pt1=2 and dx=0.5 and z=70
dpt3 = [18.05, 12.55, 9.63, 7.812, 6.57, 5.67, 4.99, 4.453, 4.02, 3.662, 3.363, 3.113, 2.895, 2.705, 2.54, 2.394, 2.263, 2.145];


figure(1);
grid on;
title('Minimum Separation (dpt)');
xlabel('NO. of Antenna');
ylabel('Minimum Separation (dpt)');

hold on;
plot(N, dpt1, 'r');
plot(N, dpt2, 'g');
plot(N, dpt3, 'b');
hold off;

lgd = legend(sprintf('pt1 = %g cm, \\lambda = %g cm, \\Deltax = %g cm, Z = %g cm ', 2, 0.4, 0.5, 30),...
          sprintf('pt1 = %g cm, \\lambda = %g cm, \\Deltax = %g cm, Z = %g cm ', 2, 0.4, 0.5, 50),...
          sprintf('pt1 = %g cm, \\lambda = %g cm, \\Deltax = %g cm, Z = %g cm ', 2, 0.4, 0.5, 70));
  title(lgd,' Min Separation (dpt) ');
```

[image: my legend title]

I tried several times and tried many codes but I did not reach any results...

Comment: Title shows up on 2023b. [Legend text properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.illustration.legend.text-properties.html) page seems to indicate that >=2016a is needed.

Comment: I don't have access to MatLab R2014, but if I remember correctly, at that time the legend was actually an axes, if so you could use its handle to add some text with the [text function](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html)